# Parse JSON object to use in Apex item select list

Tags: json, oracle-apex

I am trying to parse a JSON object into an APEX select list. There are ways to parse a JSON object, but I have not yet come across or figured a way to parse a JSON object and use it as a select list in the Apex application. Most questions have been around generating JSON from the Apex data. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

The data I want to parse (simpler example) is as below:

```
    {
  "verumModelObjectName": "Address",
  "verumObjectList": [
    {
      "locationID": "20005",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31083",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31118",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "32185",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "32138",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "32070",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "32094",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "20006",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "32196",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "41057",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31032",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "33212",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "3558",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "33126",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31007",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "33127",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31100",
      "country": "ASM"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "20008",
      "country": "AUS"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "20591",
      "country": "AUS"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31125",
      "country": "AUS"
    }]
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

Comment: Could you post your object definition and what should be on the select list?

Comment: So, you would like to show the country and return the locationID in the Select list?

Comment: Hi, I would only like to show the Country in the select list. Thanks!

Comment: So in this case it should be "ARE,ARG,ASM,AUS"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you check apex_json package in 5.0 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29640

you can parse your data by using this package 
and then for select list you should create a dynamic select list with d display and r return values as below. it should work

```
 select col1 d, col2 r
from xmltable (
        '/json/verumObjectList/row'
        passing apex_json.to_xmltype('

    {
  "verumModelObjectName": "Address",
  "verumObjectList": [
    {
      "locationID": "20005",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31083",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31118",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "32185",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "32138",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "32070",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "32094",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "20006",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "32196",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "41057",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31032",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "33212",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "3558",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "33126",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31007",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "33127",
      "country": "ARG"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31100",
      "country": "ASM"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "20008",
      "country": "AUS"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "20591",
      "country": "AUS"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31125",
      "country": "AUS"
    }],
  "statusCode": 200
}


')
        columns
           col1 number path '/row/locationID',
           col2 varchar2(5) path '/row/country' );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea. The portal is down currently, so I'll try it out as soon as I can use the API! :)