# Parse JSON array in PL/SQL

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

PL/SQL newbie here.

I am using Oracle APEX as my REST server and I am sending a JSON array (`items`) from my app to the REST server. The JSON contains logs, of which there could be 100s. I can send them successfully one by one, but that's not efficient so I want to be able to send a JSON array containing the logs instead.

Here is some test JSON:

```
{
    "items": [{
        "source": "00000999",
        "message": "test1"
    }, {
        "source": "00000999",
        "message": "test2"
    }, {
        "source": "00000999",
        "message": "test3"
    }, {
        "source": "00000999",
        "message": "test4"
    }]
}
```

Once I can parse that JSON array, I will then be adding them to the database as separate rows.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
items varchar2(2000):= '{"items":[{"source": "00000999","message": "test1"}, {"source": "00000999","message": "test2"}, {"source": "00000999","message": "test3"}, {"source": "00000999","message": "test4"}]}';
v_source varchar2(100);
   v_message varchar2(2000);
   v_json_list json_list;
   v_json_list2 json_list;
begin
   v_json_list := json_list(items);
   v_json_list2 := json_ext.get_string(json(v_json_list.GET(0)),'items');
   for i in 1..v_json_list2.count
      loop
         begin 
            v_source := json_ext.get_string(json(v_json_list2.GET(i)),'source');
            v_message := json_ext.get_string(json(v_json_list2.GET(i)),'message');
            ca_log_pak.log_info(v_source, v_message);
         end;
      end loop;
   commit;

   dbms_output.put_line('Y');


exception 
   when others then

      dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM); 
end;
```

This is throwing an error saying `expression is of the wrong type` on `v_json_list := json_list(items);`

Can someone show me how to parse the `items` array properly?

Thanks

Comment: Error is self descriptive. "Wrong type"

Comment: Could you suggest a type I can use, instead of json_list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your JSON string should be like this:

```
[{"source": "00000999","message": "test1"}, {"source": "00000999","message": "test2"}, {"source": "00000999","message": "test3"}, {"source": "00000999","message": "test4"}]
```

Try this:

```
DECLARE
  items VARCHAR2(2000):= '{"items":[{"source": "00000999","message": "test1"}, {"source": "00000999","message": "test2"}, {"source": "00000999","message": "test3"}, {"source": "00000999","message": "test4"}]}';
  my_json json_list   := json_list(LTRIM(RTRIM(items,'}'), '{"items":'));
  listElement json_value;
  jsonObj json;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..my_json.count
  LOOP
    listElement := my_json.get(i);
    jsonObj     := json(listElement);
    dbms_output.put_line(jsonObj.json_data(1).mapname);
    dbms_output.put_line(jsonObj.json_data(1).str);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Is it possible using the existing JSON I have? It is being auto-generated from the client side and I think the effort to change it on the client is more than if there's a simple fix on the server side. Thanks.

Comment: What If you remove the extra text from the beginning and end of string? Something like `LTRIM(RTRIM(<source>,'}'), '{"items":')` I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use apex_json package in 5.0
by using it you can convert your data to an adhoc xmltable and insert into your permanent table with INSERT INTO SELECT concept.
you can see the sample of apexjson and xml table at

[Parse JSON object to use in Apex item select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603894/parse-json-object-to-use-in-apex-item-select-list/32650916#32650916)